# Несовершеннолетняя девушка?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Это четверо мужчин и семь женщин, в том числе несовершеннолетняя
>   девушка.

Как можно было бы исправить фразу? Можно назвать её корректной?

Comment: А сомнения по поводу плеоназма? Так ведь, с одной стороны, "девушка" не обязательно должна быть совершеннолетней, а с другой — "несовершеннолетняя" может быть ещё девочкой.

Comment: Почему «может быть», несовершеннолетняя и есть девочка. Ведь    речь идёт о возрасте, не более.

Comment: О возрасте, о чём же ещё?! Девочка — это ребёнок или подросток, но если девушке 17 лет, то вряд ли правильно называть её девочкой. (Хотя иногда так могут говорить, чтобы подчеркнуть инфантильность и/или т.п.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструкцию типа "женщины, в том числе девушка (девушки)" нахожу подходящей только для юмористического рассказа.

Вам нужна точность изложения? Тогда такие варианты:

**Это четверо мужчин, шесть женщин и одна несовершеннолетняя.**

**Это четверо мужчин, шесть женщин и одна девушка, не достигшая совершеннолетия.**

**Это четверо мужчин, шесть женщин и одна девушка-подросток.**

**Это четверо мужчин, шесть женщин и одна несовершеннолетняя девушка.**

В повседневной речи слова *женщина* означает не только принадлежность к женскому полу, но и возраст.

Несовершеннолетняя может быть и маленькой девочкой. Если надо уточнить ее возраст, то необходимо добавить какое-то слово.

*Несовершеннолетняя девушка* звучот как-то непривычно. Я бы предпочел *девушка-подросток* или *девушка, не достигшая совершеннолетия*.

Comment: Первое — в точку, но вот далее... Хотя девушка-подросток тоже очень неплохо.

Comment: "Девушка-подросток" для 17-летней девушки уже не подойдёт.

Comment: Девушка, не достигшая совершеннолетия. (дополнил ответ)

Comment: Прискорбно и странно, но последнее (не достигшая совершеннолетия) более всего уместно, т.к. фраза о жертвах была или о пострадавших. Из контекста вырванная она такой не выгдядит.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы оставил как есть. Тут тот самый случай, когда лучшее - враг хорошего.

Править нужно только тогда, когда понятно, либо зачем править, либо как править. То есть либо фраза настолько плоха, что её нельзя оставлять как есть, либо сразу видно, что именно можно улучшить. В вашем же случае даже причина ваших сомнений не совсем понятна, а уж об очевидном улучшении и говорить не приходится - все варианты не будут свободны от каких-то шероховатостей.

Плеоназм неочевиден. Несовершеннолетним может быть и мальчик, а противопоставление женщина-девочка не так однозначно, как может показаться. В криминальных хрониках несовершеннолетние "девочки", простите, редко встречаются после шестнадцати.

Так что для репортажа - вполне.
Ну а для протокола слово "девочка" просто неуместно. Там, согласен, понятие "несовершеннолетняя" самодостаточно. Правда, если такой текст переводной или предназначен для перевода, то совсем точно будет ***"несовершеннолетнее лицо женского пола"***, ибо нужные понятия в большинстве распространенных языков (кроме славянских) не имеют нужной гендерной выразительности.
Но это уже казуальные варианты для нотариального перевода.

Comment: _оставлять, как есть_ — не думаю, что нужна запятая, но править не рискнул. Ответ поддержал.

Comment: @grizzly запятая не нужна, но так у меня ж её и не было?! Хотя вопрос сам по себе интересный, тут многие путаются и запятую ставят. За остальные правки - спасибо, у меня не хватило сил сразу проверить.... Ой, понял. Она в другом месте. Спасибо, она не нужна, конечно. Это я так отредактировал неудачно.

Answer (score 1):

Это четверо мужчин и семь женщин, включая несовершеннолетнюю

(уточнять, что речь не о девочке, а более взрослой особе, не нужно, потому что мы уже обозначили её принадлежность к женщинам)

**Ещё вариант:** Это четверо мужчин и семь женщин, считая несовершеннолетнюю

Comment: Математика не сходится (6+1=7 :)

Comment: Конечно, было **семь** женщин, включая несовершеннолетнюю. Приемлемо, по-моему. Не очень четко, но интуитивно понятно.   Ясно, что женщины здесь — это только половая принадлежность. С другой стороны можно догадаться, что это не маленькая девочка или возраст несовершеннолетней не имеет значения (в противном случае, указали бы явно, что она девочка).

Comment: Всё правильно: несовершеннолетняя — две в одной — ж. р., но и не женщина.ещё: семь женщин, включая несовершеннолетнюю (женщину же).

Comment: Исправил. Была описка "шесть" вместо "семь", думаю, меня поняли

Comment: "Включая (или исключая) кого-то" логичнее говорить в случаях, когда этот кто-то ранее был упомянут (напр. сначала говорилось о большей группе подозреваемых, среди которых была Н., а затем называется выявленный состав преступной группы). Поэтому вряд ли данный вариант точнее исходного.

Comment: Какая-то у Вас вольная трактовка слова "включая". Словарь не устанавливает этих ограничений.

Comment: В данном контексте "в том числе" предпочтительнее, чем "включая".

Comment: При всём уважении, в Вашем утверждении нет аргумента или ссылки на правило. Я могу написать зеркально: "включая" предпочтительнее, чем "в том числе". Чем будем измерять "предпочтительность"? Это субъективная оценка.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю выражение "несовершеннолетняя девушка" вполне корректным. Приведу в подтверждение пару цитат известных писателей.

> ...Эта возможность заключается в том, что он заявит, что тот похитил
>   несовершеннолетнюю девушку. (Александр Дюма)
>
> – Девчонки! Девчонки! – закричала почти несовершеннолетняя девушка.
>   (Василий Аксёнов)

(Правда я не могу понять, что значит здесь "почти", но это в данном случае не существенно.)

Comment: Что значит здесь "почти" мне тоже неведомо, да и с тов. Дюма через переводчика не хотелось бы общаться: что он имел в виду — кто знает.

Comment: @shampar С замечанием про Дюма согласен. Посмотрел два перевода: в одном "девушка", в другом — "девочка". Поискать Вам ещё цитат?

Comment: Не стоит, спасибо. Вопрос, который задан имел бы решение, если бы все мы условились, что нельзя совершеннолетие (термин закона) привязывать к представлению о физической кондиции, если так можно сказать.

Comment: Можно принять слова "несовершеннолетняя девушка", но конструкцию типа "женщины, в том числе девушка (девушки)" нахожу подходящей только для юмористического рассказа.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что возможна и такая интерпретация этого предложения:
**Это четверо мужчин и семь женщин, одна из которых несовершеннолетняя.**

"Женщины" — это указание на количество лиц женского пола (вне зависимости от возраста).
"Несовершеннолетняя" — это указание на определенную возрастную границу, которую одна из женщин (или лиц женского пола) ещё не достигла.

Такая формулировка *нейтральна* для всех стран, в том числе и с "нестандартным" возрастом совершеннолетия (например: Индонезия — 15 лет; Монако — 21 год).

Comment: Чем этот ответ отличается от того, что написал  @ТретийГлаз?

Comment: Вот этим: _Это четверо мужчин и шесть женщин, включая несовершеннолетнюю_. 1. Лиц женского пола - семь. 2. Некоторые путают термин "включая" (это видно из предложения).Grizzly правильно написал: математика не сходится.

Comment: Согласен. Тогда скопирую из моих комментов к ответу, который дал @ТретийГлаз: Приемлемо, по-моему. Не очень четко, но интуитивно понятно. Ясно, что женщины здесь — это только половая принадлежность. С другой стороны можно догадаться, что это не маленькая девочка или возраст несовершеннолетней не имеет значения (в противном случае, указали бы явно, что она девочка).